# Writing Image Gallery (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, gallery

I just want to ask if anyone could help me write that image gallery?

Screenshot how it should look like: [link](http://uss.feri.uni-mb.si/images/Vaje/Vaja11/slika08.png)

This is what i come up with:

```
jsgalerija.html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="cs" lang="cs">
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>JS Galerija</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsGalerija.css"  />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jsGalerija.js"></script>

     </head>
     <body onLoad="galerija();">
      <table class="galerija">
        <tr><th>Seznam</th><th>Slika</th></tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="seznam"></td>
          <td id="slika">Klikni na sliko v seznamu!</td>
        </tr>
      </table>       
     </body>
    </html>


jsGalerija.js    
function galerija() 
    {
        images = new Array();
        images[0]="slike/image1.jpg"
        images[1]="slike/image2.jpg"
        images[2]="slike/image3.jpg"
        images[3]="slike/image4.jpg"

        for(i=0; i<=3; i++) 
        {
            document.getElementById('seznam').innerHTML = '<IMG SRC="' +images[i]+ '"><br />';
            document.getElementById('slika').innerHTML = '<IMG SRC="' +images[i]+ '"><br />';
        }
    }
```

If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stupid as this answer may seem, you can use a code snippet from a site like Dynamic Drive:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/indexb.html